# Can't select item from google places autocomplete dropdown

Tags: html, google-maps, angular-material, google-places

Works with mouse as it should.

However, when used with touch, it only seems to trigger the hover state and I just get a grey highlight over the item and it's not immediately selected and value not reflected in the search box input field. It does actually select it when I press 'done' on the iPhone, but this is not how it should work, it should select and place value into input field after a tap.

I have read people having similar issues with Cordova and fast click library etc. But I am not using any of these.

After some testing it appears that this only happens if I load the angular material library, if not loaded, the places search box autocomplete behaves as expected.

Comment: What has this got to do with Angular Material?

Comment: @camden_kid it's my primary UI library, even if not used on this input, there are plenty of instances where one library/script effects the behaviour of another.

Comment: Understood. In what way do you think Angular Material is affecting the behaviour? Any chance of a CodePen, Fiddle, etc. example.

Comment: @camden_kid After further testing, it seems if  I don't load the angular material library, the autocomplete drop down for the places box works fine and items select straight away, if I do load it, the aforementioned happens. I will try to make a jsfiddle soon.

Comment: One of the things I do when there is a possible problem introduced by AM is to inspect the CSS of the element that has the problem and see if `angular-material.min.js` is in the list of styles and then turn off each AM style to see what could be causing the problem.

Comment: @camden_kid It certainly does appear to be overwriting some styles, likely even position property, will test and hopefully that would fix it.